# For loop does not return result in correct format in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written below procedure in which i want to return the output of variable value `brand_name.BRAND_NAME`. I am getting the correct output. But i want to return it in proper format. For example right now i am getting the output without header `'BRAND_NAME'` as

```
,FNC,LIDL
```

But i want to return the output with header `'BRAND_NAME'` as:

```
BRAND_NAME: FNC,LIDL
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
FUNCTION BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY
(
  IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP
, IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC IN VARCHAR2
, IN_KPI_LOG_ID IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
V_KPI_DEF_ID NUMBER := '';
V_KPI_TYPE VARCHAR2(100) := '';
V_KPI_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '';
V_BRAND_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '';
V_KPI_TYPE_ID NUMBER := '';
V_FIRST_RECORD Boolean := false;

CURSOR brand_names_cur 
IS
Select BR.NAME AS BRAND_NAME INTO V_BRAND_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION_BRAND KDB ON KD.KPI_DEF_ID = KDB.KPI_DEF_ID JOIN
RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.BRAND BR ON KDB.BRAND_ID = BR.BRAND_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

BEGIN
Select KPI_DEF_ID INTO V_KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_LOGS WHERE KPI_LOG_ID = IN_KPI_LOG_ID;

Select KT.KPI_TYPE_ID INTO V_KPI_TYPE_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

Select NAME INTO V_KPI_TYPE FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

Select KPI_NAME INTO V_KPI_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

BODY := BODY || 'KPI_TYPE : ' || V_KPI_TYPE || Chr(13) || Chr(10);
BODY := BODY || 'KPI_NAME : ' || V_KPI_NAME || Chr(13) || Chr(10);

FOR brand_name IN brand_names_cur
LOOP
if v_first_record then
  body := 'BRAND_NAME : '|| brand_name.BRAND_NAME;
  v_first_record := true;
else
  body := body || ',' || brand_name.BRAND_NAME;
  v_first_record := false;
end if;
END LOOP;    

    RETURN BODY;
END BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY;
```

Comment: where do you set v_first_record to true? It looks like it will always be false to me, so the first branch of your if statement is not executed.

Comment: yes its correct if the procedure does not return any brand name from database then it will not return in output. Sorry i forgot to mention the line where i have set it to true. I have edited my code. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be this way.

```
v_first_record := true;

FOR brand_name IN brand_names_cur
LOOP
if v_first_record then
  body := body || 'BRAND_NAME : '|| brand_name.BRAND_NAME;
  v_first_record := false;
else
  body := body || ',' || brand_name.BRAND_NAME;
end if;
END LOOP;
```

**EDIT:**
You overwrite the variable here. So add append to it...

```
body := body || 'BRAND_NAME : '|| brand_name.BRAND_NAME;
```

Comment: The output is showing now in proper format for brand_name. But now i am facing different problem. I am not getting the result in the output for KPI_TYPE and KPI_NAME. The output is only showing the result BRAND_NAME = FNC,LIDL.

Comment: Updated the answer, you are overwriting the previous value in `body` inside the loop, for first record.

Comment: I am sorry i am bit confused. Where should i add append to it ? Inside if statement or else statement ?

Comment: `body := body || 'BRAND_NAME : '|| brand_name.BRAND_NAME;`

Comment: Where should i add the above line which you have written ?